Can ColdFusion 2023 settings interfere with JavaScript?
I'm at a total loss here.
I was tasked with upgrading ColdFusion 2018 Standard to ColdFusion 2023 Enterprise.  I have the website update and running, but I'm running into an absolutely bizarre issue.
After upgrading to ColdFusion 2023, it appears that some of the JavaScript is not functioning properly.  For example, I am retrieving some JSON from a ColdFusion component.  In the browser developer tools, I can see the JSON string being returned.  Prior to the upgrade, the JS component that renders the JSON into a tree now no longer displays anything.
I don't see any console errors.  There aren't any ColdFusion errors.  Nothing.
If anyone has any insight, I would appreciate it.

Does your CF return JSON with a prepending string for security? Check your admin to see if "Prefix serialized JSON with" is checked. https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/configuring-administering/using-the-coldfusion-administrator.html

It is set and that is by design.  I have code that converts that strips the "//" from the JSON string and parses it into a JSON object.

I guess at that point, I'd start stepping through the component that renders the JSON into a tree. CF and JS don't know about each other, so new CF install shouldn't affect your JS.

@mykaf that's what I thought.  I know coincidence does not equal causality, but at this point I'm grasping at straws.

The upgrade isn't affecting any JavaScript, correct? The problem is that the CFC-based function no longer returns the correct JSON content. Are you able to run the two CF servers side-by-side? I would recommend running them locally using CommandBox so you can run the same code on both versions of CF at the same time. https://www.ortussolutions.com/products/commandbox

@AdrianJ.Moreno I uninstalled the previous version of ColdFusion.  2023 is running as a standalone instance.  I'm not sure that the CFC-based function is not working properly.  As I mentioned, I can see the HTTP call to the CFC and the response.  I guess i'm going to have to do what was suggested, deploy the debug version of the code, and step through to see what the issue is.  The other thing is that this isn't the only application to which this is happening.

I resolved the issue.
I was testing the ColdFusion 2023 migration using a development site.  I knew about the "Preserve case for Struct keys for Serialization" configuration option, and it was checked.  Checking and unchecking this options appeared to have no effect.  After I finished testing, I left this option unchecked.
I performed this testing before running through all of the ColdFusion 2023 hotfix/patches.
After running through this patching process and testing the settings again, everything worked as expected.  The possibility remains that either I messed up because it was the end of the day and I was tired, or the patching fixed an issue.
